# Как сделать динамический импорт в typescript?

Tags: typescript

**Статический импорт, все работает:**

```
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
```

**Динамический импорт, не работает:**

Первый вариант:

```
  const { FastifyAdapter, NestFastifyApplication } = await import(
    '@nestjs/platform-fastify'
  );
```

Второй вариант:

```
  const { FastifyAdapter } = await import('@nestjs/platform-fastify');
  const { NestFastifyApplication } = await import('@nestjs/platform-fastify');
```

Третий вариант:

```
  const { default: FastifyAdapter } = await import('@nestjs/platform-fastify');
  const { default: NestFastifyApplication } = await import('@nestjs/platform-fastify');
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
TS2339: Property 'NestFastifyApplication' does not exist on type '{ default: typeof import("L:/Test/nestjs-test/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-fastify/index"); FastifyAdapter: typeof FastifyAdapter; }'.
```

Как решить?

**Update:**

Функция:

```
async function fastifyBootstrap() {
  const { default: NestFastifyApplication, FastifyAdapter } = await import(
    '@nestjs/platform-fastify'
  );

  return await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
  );
}
```

Comment: а в чем собственно проблема? выбирайте какой хотите вариант, если все работают

Comment: Проблема в том, что работает только статический. Не один из динамических не работает: `TS2339: Property 'NestFastifyApplication' does not exist on type '{ default: typeof import("L:/Test/nestjs-test/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-fastify/index"); FastifyAdapter: typeof FastifyAdapter; }'.`

Comment: а что именно не работает? какая-то ошибка? проверил сейчас локально на простом примере, типы и все остальное определяется правильно

Comment: добавьте это в вопрос, плиз, что бы другие тоже видели

Comment: Не могу сейчас проверить, но предположу. А NestFastifyApplication это не интерфейс? Может динамически можно заимпортить только "реальные объекты" вроде классов, функций и переменных?... Все таки дин импорт происходит в рантайме, а в рантайме интерфейса нет

Comment: Хорошее предположение! Да, интерфейс. Вероятно, в этом и проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если прочитать ошибку, то должно быть так:

```
const { default: NestFastifyApplication, FastifyAdapter } = await import('@nestjs/platform-fastify');
```

Хотя этому соответствует другой статический импорт:

```
import NestFastifyApplication, { FastifyAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
```

> TS2749: 'NestFastifyApplication' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof NestFastifyApplication'?

Так типы есть только при компиляции - импортируй явно только тип в коде, а в динамический импорт пихай только реально существующие сущности:

```
import type { NestFastifyApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify'

const { FastifyAdapter } = await import('@nestjs/platform-fastify')
```

Comment: Теперь получаю: `TS2749: 'NestFastifyApplication' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof NestFastifyApplication'?` P.S Всю функцию приложил в вопрос.

Comment: @Lasna1, обновил.

Comment: Cупер! Век живи - век учись.